# "php_connect_nonb() failed: Operation now in progress (115)" happens intermittently

Tags: php, linux, ftp

We send some files across to a third party with a PHP cron job via FTP.

However sometimes we get the following error:

```
ErrorException [ 2 ]: ftp_put(): php_connect_nonb() failed: Operation 
now in progress (115) ~ MODPATH/fileop/classes/Drivers/Fileop/Ftp.php [ 37 ]
```

When I say "sometimes" I mean exactly that; most times it goes across fine but about 1 in 5 times we get that error. It's not to do with the files themselves, because they will go happily if we try again.

We've found similar issues online - relating to a [bug in PHP](http://www.elitehosts.com/blog/php-ftp-passive-ftp-server-behind-nat-nightmare/) with NAT devices or to do with firewall configuration but again the implication is that if this were the case it would *never* work.

So, why would this work some times and not others?

Answer (score 25):

```
ftp_set_option($ftpconn, FTP_USEPASVADDRESS, false);
```

This line of code before setting passivity of the connection `ftp_pasv($ftpconn, true);`

Solved my problem

Comment: My code: 

`$conn = ftp_connect($server);
$login = ftp_login($conn, $username, $password);
ftp_set_option($conn, FTP_USEPASVADDRESS, false);
ftp_pasv($conn, true);
ftp_put($conn, $remote_file, $file, FTP_ASCII);`

Comment: To save people having to look up what this actually does: `When FTP_USEPASVADDRESS is disabled, PHP will ignore the IP address returned by the FTP server in response to the PASV command and instead use the IP address that was supplied in the ftp_connect(). Value must be a boolean`

Answer (score 11):

[FTP(S) uses random ports to set up data connections](http://www.slacksite.com/other/ftp.html); an intermittent success rate indicates that not all ports are allowed by a firewall on the client and/or server machines. The port range for incoming (PASV) data connections can be set in the FTP server.

[This page](http://www.mdjnet.dk/ftp.html) has a nice summary:

> The easy way is to simply allow FTP servers and clients unlimited
>   access through your firewall, but if you like to limit their access to
>   "known" ports, you have to understand the 4 different scenarios.
>
> 1) The FTP server should be allowed to accept TCP connections to port
>   21, and to make TCP connections from port 20 to any (remote ephemeral)
>   port.
>
> 2) The FTP server should be allowed to accept TCP connections to port
>   21, AND to accept TCP connections to any ephemeral port as well!
>
> 3) The FTP client should be allowed to make TCP connections to port
>   21, and to accept TCP connections from port 20 to any ephemeral port.
>
> 4) The FTP client should be allowed to make TCP connections to port
>   21, and to make TCP connections to any other (remote ephemeral) port
>   as well!

Answer (score 2):

So, I'm writing this answer after doing some investigation on my FTP server and reading the link you provided elitehosts.com.

I'm using FileZilla FTP server, and there is a specific setting that I had to enter to make it work.  Going into the server settings, there is an area titled "Passive mode settings".  In that dialog, there is an area titled "IPv4 specific", and within that area there is a setting labeled "External Server IP Address for passive mode transfers:".  It's a radio button selection set, and it was on "Default", but since the FTP server is NAT'ed, I changed that radio selection from "Default" to "Use the following IP:" and entered in the external-facing IP address of my gateway provided by my ISP.

After I set this up, it worked!  Not terribly sure if your FTP server is NAT'ed, but I thought I would provide the answer on this thread because it seems related.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Cees answer, I am running vsftp on ec2 and had to comment out the listen_ipv6=YES, listen=YES then "service vsftpd restart".

Although documentation says it will listen on ipv4 as well it wasn't and this resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

For me all I had to do was to remove the `ftp_pasv( $ftpconn, true );` and everything worked perfectly. I'm not yet sure why but I am trying to find out and I will surely come back when I do get the reason behind it.

Comment: So? Did you get to find the reason. This also happened to me this afternoon and I did as you said and it just worked.

Comment: well I did do some investigation and looks like you can not trust the solution I put forward...soon as I get best reliable solution I will share

Answer (score 0):

This should be a comment under jj_dev2 comment, but I cannot add one due to reputation. But maybe it will be helpful for someone, so I post it here.

We had the same issue as described in the original post. In our case it worked with many customers - except one.

The solution in jj_dev2 comment did work for us. So we investigated what does `ftp_set_option($conn, FTP_USEPASVADDRESS, false)` actually do. And based on that we found out that in fact customer's FTPS server was configured incorrectly.

In response to PASV command (`ftp_pasv($conn, true)`) FTP server returns an IP address which the PHP FTP client then will use for data transfers. In our case the FTP server was returning an internal IP address and not the public IP address that we connect to. Customer had to fix their FTP server settings so FTP server would send external IP address in the PASV command response.