# PHP ftp upload error

Tags: php, ftp

I'm encountering strange behavior with a simple PHP script that uploads a file to a ftp server.

I've created the following stripped down version of my code which produces the same error:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
echo phpversion();

$ftpUrl = "mydomain";
$ftpUserName = "myuser";
$ftpPassword = 'mypass';    

$fileContents = "test"; 
file_put_contents('text.txt', $fileContents);


//open ftp connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftpUrl, 1030);

 if(!$conn_id)
    die('error while connecting to ftp');

$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftpUserName, $ftpPassword);

 if (!$login_result) 
    die('ftp login failed!');

//switch to passive mode
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);

 //upload file to ftp
try
{
    $fileToUpload = fopen('text.txt', 'r');

    if($fileToUpload == false)
        die('can\'t open file to send!');

    $upload = ftp_fput($conn_id, 'testfile.txt', $fileToUpload, FTP_ASCII);
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    fclose($fileToUpload);
    ftp_close($conn_id);
    die('Error while uploading to ftp');            
}

fclose($fileToUpload);
ftp_close($conn_id);

if (!$upload) 
    die('ftp upload failed');
```

?>

On the client's ftp server I get the following error when running the script. (the error occurs when trying to upload the file, setting up the connection an logging in works)

```
Warning: ftp_fput() [function.ftp-fput]: php_connect_nonb() failed: Operation now in progress (115) in {path} on line 38

Warning: ftp_fput() [function.ftp-fput]: Type set to A in {path} on line 38
ftp upload failed
```

- Uploading the same file with filezilla to this ftp server works fine.
- The file only contains a few lines of text.
- When running this script on a different server, it works fine.

The server uses php version 5.3.28

I've been struggling with this error for hours now and it is driving me crazy. Any clues?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["php\_connect\_nonb() failed: Operation now in progress (115)" happens intermittently](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15688331/php-connect-nonb-failed-operation-now-in-progress-115-happens-intermitten)

Comment: Emm, the port shouldn't be 21 ?

Answer (score -1):

Ftp_put() takes a file *name* as a parameter, you are passing a file *handle*

Try

```
ftp_put($conn_id,'testfile.txt', 'test.txt', FTP_ASCII);
```

Comment: This gives me the same error. The strange part is, passing in a file handle works on a different ftp server (with slightly different php version).