# php_connect_nonb() failed: Operation now in progress

Tags: php

I'm getting this error while using ftp_nlist() function. I can logged in to FTP but can not list/read files from FTP. What is the problem?

Comment: did you have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15688331/php-connect-nonb-failed-operation-now-in-progress-115-happens-intermitten

Comment: Write your code example, please. It may be error in functions call order.

Comment: if (ftp_get($conn_id, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_BINARY))
  {
  echo "Successfully written to $local_file\n";
  }
   else
  {
  echo "There was a problem\n";
  }

Comment: Below line of code giving me error like php_connect_nonb() failed:
$list_file = ftp_nlist($conn_id, '.');

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["php\_connect\_nonb() failed: Operation now in progress (115)" happens intermittently](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15688331/php-connect-nonb-failed-operation-now-in-progress-115-happens-intermitten)

Answer (score 0):

For a basic ftp connections you can use this code from php.net

```
<?php

// set up basic connection. #ftpserver can be localhost or ftp.yourdomain.net
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
//To bypass a firewall use ftp_pasv
ftp_pasv($conn_id,true);
// login with your ftp username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

// get contents of the current directory

$contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, ".");

// output $contents
var_dump($contents);

?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-nlist.php

Comment: You should first do the login, before the ftp_pasv command.