# php ftp_nlist function returns 504 Gateway Timeout error

Tags: php

I have a problem with ftp_nlist function, namely it returns 504 Gateway timeout error when I run the code on production server, on localhost works fine.

My code is:

```
   $connection_id = ftp_connect( $host, $port, $timeout );

  if ( $connection_id === false ) {
    throw new \Exception( 'Unable to connect to FTP Server. Check the connection details and try again.' );
  }

  $login = @ftp_login($connection_id,  $username,  $password);

  if ( $login !== true ) {
    $error = 'Unable to log in. Check your username or password and try again.';
    throw new \Exception( $error );
  }

  $check_dir = @ftp_chdir( $connection_id, $ftp_folder );

  if ( !$check_dir ) {
    $error = 'Couldn\'t find directory '. esc_attr( $ftp_folder ).' on '. esc_attr( $host );
    throw new \Exception( $error );
  }

  $check_file = @ftp_nlist( $connection_id, $ftp_folder ) ?: array();

  // This is where error occurs
```

I've tried to set the following:

```
 ftp_set_option($connection_id, FTP_USEPASVADDRESS, false); // set ftp option
  ftp_pasv($connection_id, true); //make connection to passive mode
```

after ftp_login function and doesn't work either.

Any idea what might be the problem here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

No idea if the issue is fixed now but I had the same problem. I think it is a firewall problem which is activated most of the time. To fix it, I just had to add this line:

```
ftp_pasv($ftp_conn,true);
```

Hope that'll help someone!

Comment: Please add a link to the official documentation and elaborate on all the consequences of this setting. See also [How To Answer Well](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting as far as logging in and changing directories, I'm assuming it isn't an issue with connecting to the server initially.

Removing the `@` in front of the `ftp_nlist()` might give you more information on the nature of the error condition.

Offhand, my only thought is that the directory listing is so long that your connection is timing out before the server can return it. How long is your script taking to reach this error?

Do you get the same behavior if you use [`ftp_rawlist()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-rawlist.php) or [`ftp_mlsd()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-mlsd.php)?

Comment: Removing @ didn't help. ftp_rawlist() times out, too, ftp_mlsd() returns false. There are only 2 files in the directory

Comment: What code comes after the `ftp_nlist()` call? I know you mentioned seeing a reference to a 504, but can you provide a full error message / stack trace?

Comment: I get a blank page with:
504 Gateway Time-out
The server didn't respond in time.

The code after ftp_nlist() is never run

Comment: Perhaps [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14755120/ftp-by-host-name-504-gateway-timeout) might help?

Comment: it didn't work.I removed the code with ftp_nlist() and now ftp_get() is having the same problem. It works on my local site though. Can it be some server configuration problem?

Comment: Possible. Is there any major difference between your local site and the server you're having issues with?

Comment: The only difference I noticed was php version but changing didn't help. I'm getting such errors:
PHP Warning:  ftp_get(): php_connect_nonb() failed: Operation now in progress (115)
and
PHP Warning:  ftp_get(): Type set to I.

Comment: This thread might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15688331/php-connect-nonb-failed-operation-now-in-progress-115-happens-intermitten